# I need to find the Z-score of a population to use as a cutoff point in order to reduce the value sum of numbers to a new sum

Tags: z-score

This may be tough to describe, but I'll give it a shot. I am setting up an analysis that produces a large set of numbers. Let's call this Analysis 1 (A1). If I run A1 and return 60 numbers with a value equaling 1000, but then want to reduce that sum to 900 by removing numbers from the population of numbers, starting from the lowest number and working my way up, how would I go about doing this?

My thinking right now leads me to believe that the answer lies in the Z-score. If I can figure out the Z-score value of the cutoff point (as in if you remove all the numbers with a Z-score that is lower than this Z-score), then I can remove those and come out with a sum that is close to my target sum (understanding that it may not be possible to make it exact).

I may be going about this the wrong way, and if so, let me know. If finding the cutoff Z-score is the right way to go, then I need help finding out what that number is.

Appreciate any help I can get on this!

Comment: Why don't you just sort your 60 numbers in ascending order, then remove the first (smallest) ones until the sum of the removed numbers is 100? Then the others will sum to 900.

Comment: Unfortunately, the program I'm using doesn't work like that. I need this to be automated. It's an equation that I'm going to run several times with several different sets of numbers of varying population and value size. Basically, every part of this equation is a variable

Comment: Re "how do I go about doing this:" you describe the brute-force approach in the first paragraph.The computing time is asymptotically $O(n\log(n))$ due to the sorting.  With huge datasets you would use a binary search that finds these numbers; it would be slightly more efficient ($O(n)$ but with a substantial coefficient). That's overkill in your case.  But, as others have already remarked, exploiting Z-scores will be of no help unless you can be assured the standardized distributions of these sets of numbers are remarkably similar.

Answer (score 2):

In R, begin by getting 60 numbers that sum to 1000:

```
set.seed(823)
x = sort(rnorm(60, 29, 4))
x = 1000*x/sum(x)
sum(x)
[1] 1000
```

So the 60 elements of `x` sum to exactly 1000, and they are sorted in
ascending order of size. Now we need to get rid of a few of the smallest
numbers at the start, as @StephanKolassa has suggested, so the sum will be near 900. Here is an automated method.

Begin by finding the cumulative sums `s` of numbers in `x`, and then find where
the cumulative sum first exceeds 100. For my sequence that is at the 8th element.

```
s = cumsum(x)
i = which.max(s > 100); i
[1] 8
s[i]
[1] 102.5158
```

Now the numbers in `x` beyond the 8th position will sum to about 900, as required.

```
y = x[(i+1):60]
sum(y)
[1] 897.4842
```

There may be more elegant R code that does the same thing, but I hope this
method is transparent.

Comment: I believe I need to rephrase my question. Basically, I'm looking for an equation that I can plug into my program. I'm not using a programming language, but, rather, a tool that a programming language created. Forget the program for a second though, as this would get me there: If I want to take 10% off of my total sum, is there a mathematical equation or set of equations that can help me figure out what bottom percentage of the population to get rid of to reach that new sum?

Comment: No, there is no such equation, simply because there are far too many ways to have 60 numbers that sum to 1000. Any programming environment can be taught to sort numbers (and automatically, too, of course), so I'm afraid you will need to be more specific about what tools you are using and why sort-and-delete will not work - because it *is* the simplest way. In any case, this sounds like it would be more on-topic at StackOverflow, because there really is no statistics or Machine Learning involved.

Comment: It occurs to me that this might be a convoluted way of asking some sort of question about truncated normal distributions. If so, please ask that question directly. // If this really is a programming question, then please follow @StephanKolassa's advice about asking (a clarified version of) it in an appropriate forum.